# How do you using $_POST values to create an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, forms, array-merge, array-push

I am trying to divide $_POST values into different arrays to check its values. I am trying to retain both the $key and $values as an associative array.  For now, only `array_push` works, but not `array_merge`. Array_merge returns an empty array for me. Can someone help?

```
$reg_word = $reg_alpha = $reg_paragraph = array();


foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value){
        if (in_array($key, $alpha_numbers)){    
            array_push($reg_word, $value);
        } else

        if (in_array($key, $alpha)){
            array_push($reg_alpha, $value);
        } else

        if (in_array($key, $paragraph)){
            array_push($reg_paragraph, $value);
        }
    }
```

Displays

```
Array ( [0] => St. John [1] => M [2] => kjkjk ) 
Array ( [0] => HKG ) 
Array ( [0] => kjkj )
```

I want it to display `Array( Location => St. John)` etc.

Comment: try with [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: where does key name `Location` comes from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then stop using `array_push()`; just assign.

```
$arr[$key] = $val;
```

Comment: In his case, $arr[$key] = $value;